# Angular 2 Material MD Menu is not working

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I  have imported "MdMenuModule" in my root and trying to use md-menu, it is not working.

```html
<button md-icon-button [mdMenuTriggerFor]="menu">
  <span> Menu </span>
</button>
<md-menu #menu="mdMenu">
  <button md-menu-item>
    <span>Redial</span>
  </button>
  <button md-menu-item disabled>
    <span>Check voicemail</span>
  </button>
  <button md-menu-item>
    <span>Disable alerts</span>
  </button>
</md-menu>
```

But it's throwing following error.

Unexpected module 'MdMenuModule' declared by the module 'SharedModule'. Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation.

Comment: Add MdMenuModule to imports array instead of declarations

Answer (score 1):

you clearly imported the `MdMenuModule` in the wrong place in your module called 'SharedModule'. So you should simply move the `MdMenuModule` declaration from the declarations array to the imports array as it's a module not a component or a directive or a pipe.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    //Components, Pipes or Directives here, remove the MdMenuModule
  ],
  imports: [
    //add it here
    MdMenuModule 
  ],
  providers: [
   //services go here
   ]
})
export class SharedModule{ }
```

Comment: If i add that in imports, I am getting following error.   Can't bind to 'mdMenuTriggerFor' since it isn't a known property of 'i'

Comment: I believe you want to use 'i' as the hook of the md-menu tag so you should have the following in your template next to the button triggering the menu `<md-menu #i="mdMenu">`

Answer (score -1):

Add in your app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { MaterialModule } from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
imports: [
   ....
  MaterialModule,
   ....
]
})
```

Comment: Since `MaterialModule` is deprecated, it shouldn't be used.